# Generate line number / "index" within a range from a date seed value

Tags: shell-script, grep, date

I'm trying to create a bash script to display a word of the day (random for each day). I have a dictionary file that on each line has a word and its definition.

I'd like to use `date` to get a unique value for each day. Like so

```
today=$(date '+%Y%m%d') # will return 20160616 (for today)
```

Now I'd like to use this value to generate a line number for me to grab from the dictionary file.

My dictionary is `86036` lines long so I need to convert `$today` to a value between `1` and `86036`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: It should generate the same random number (between 1..86036) for each 24-hour period? Also -- I just did the math and you won't run out of words for ~235 years.

Comment: Does there need to be randomness in the selection? If the end-users don't know the contents of the file, would a sequential walk through the file be acceptable? (given that humans don't yet live for 235 years, it's unlikely anyone would be offended by a repeat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat different solution: Scramble the lines in your text files with a cron job every day. Your script then picks the first line.

Cron job (requires a `sort` that can "sort" data randomly with `-R`):

```
0 0 * * * sort -R -o wotd_data.txt wotd_data.txt
```

Or, if your `cron` understands `@daily` (see `man 5 crontab`):

```
@daily sort -R -o wotd_data.txt wotd_data.txt
```

Script:

```
head -n 1 wotd_data.txt
```

Full paths to `wotd_data.txt` are obviously required.

Answer (score 2):

Modulus math!

```
$ today=`date +%Y%m%d`
$ echo $(( today % 86036 + 1 ))
28193
```

... with possibly the 86036 instead being `wc -l that file` in the event the length of that file changes ...

Comment: That's a decent solution however it would mean that I'd be starting at line `28193` then I would consecutively go through each entry in the dictionary until I hit the end. This isn't really what I want as it isn't really random in any way

Comment: If you wanted random, then why not just use `$RANDOM`?

Comment: @Kusalananda because I want to use today's date as a unique seed so every time I run the script today I will get the same index/line number

Comment: Setting `RANDOM` to a number will seed it...

Comment: ... but obviously you can't seed `RANDOM` every time you run your script.... hmm. Let me think.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `RANDOM` variable of your shell to get a random number, but seed the random number generator with today's date first (if the script hasn't been used since midnight). Then pick that line out of the file.

In other words (Bash below)...

```
wotd_data="wotd_data.txt"

stamp="$HOME/.wotd-stamp"
stamp_random="$HOME/.wotd-random"

date_now=$( date +"%Y%m%d" )

if [ -f "$stamp" ]; then
    date_last=$( <"$stamp" )
else
    date_last=0
fi

if [ "$date_last" != "$date_now" ]; then
    RANDOM="$date_now"
    echo "$date_now" >"$stamp"
else
    RANDOM=$( <"$stamp_random" )
fi

number=$RANDOM
echo $number >"$stamp_random"

number=$RANDOM$RANDOM  # See the "Edit #2" note below

data_length=$( wc -l <"$wotd_data" )

line=$(( 1 + ( number % data_length ) ))

sed -n "${line}p" "$wotd_data"
```

This uses a time-stamp file in the user's `$HOME` to keep track of when they last ran the command.  If it wasn't today, then re-seed `$RANDOM` with today's date and write today's date into the file.

EDIT #1: I had to also store the last used random number since `$RANDOM` is local to the current shell.  The seeding doesn't otherwise carry over to the next invocation of the script.  I store that in a separate "random stamp" file.  You might want to change this to use only one file for both the date of the last invocation and the last used random number.

EDIT #2: Can anyone spot the problem with my original code? Well, `$RANDOM` will never be more than 32767 (16 bits), and the file was said to have more lines than this. This means that maybe using `$RANDOM` alone may not be a good idea. This is why I resort to simply concatenating `$RANDOM` with itself, generating a longer random number. The seeding and the "random stamp" file is not affected by this.

EDIT #3: Just noticed that the OP requested "the same line every time the script is run on a particular day" (in a comment that my brain didn't grok late last night), which is exactly what my script does *not* do (it gives the same *sequence of lines* every day).  I'm leaving my solution in here anyway in case it helps someone else with similar issues of preserving the state of `$RANDOM` between script invocations.

Answer (score 1):

If a sequential walk through the file is not acceptable, then here's my suggestion; it will take more than 230 years to cover every line in the file, and will repeat words back-to-back at some yet-undetermined point in the future. I made it a bit more flexible by computing the number of lines (word definitions) in the 'words' file at run-time, so if you ever add or remove lines from the file, the script will adjust accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# number of days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00
seed=$(( ($(date +%s) / 86400) ))
# initialize RNG to this seed
RANDOM=$seed
nwords=$(wc -l < words)
# generate two random numbers (0 .. 32767), multiply them,
# modulo nwords, plus 1 -> range 1..86036
r=$(( ((RANDOM * RANDOM) % nwords) + 1 ))
# print that line from the 'words' file
sed -n "${r}p" words
```